# Conditional breakpoint in Intel debugger (idbc)

Tags: debugging, intel-fortran

Well, i´m using the intel fortran debugger for command line (`idbc`) but i can´t find how to do a conditional breakpoint.

I mean, i would like the debugger to stop the program only if something happens. For example, i have a subroutine called `example(a,b,c)` which is called several times, but I only want the debugger to stop the program if the variable `a` has some determined value.

I know that this [can be done easily](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-win/GUID-85CD2951-F0C6-4BCB-961F-9CA3A315BB6E.htm#ADDING_CONDITIONS) in the GUI version, but i have been reading [the manual of the command line version](http://scv.bu.edu/computation/linuxcluster/docs/intel_comp_docs_7.1/docs/idb_debugger_manual.htm#guide.pause.tab.stat) and i couldn´t find the way.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I just found the answer in [this page](http://denali.princeton.edu/IntelXe2011/debugger/cl/commandref/gdb_mode/cmd_condition.htm). Once you define the breakpoint with

```
(idb) break <line_number>
```

You get a `Breakpoint ID`, that you can see with the command `info breakpoints`

```
(idb) info breakpoints
<IDnumber>     <Brakpoint_type>  .....    <file and line>
```

to add a condition to a breakpoint you should use the command `condition`:

```
(idb) condition <IDnumber> <condition>
```

for example

```
(idb) condition 1 ielem==30000
```

I think that this can be helpful for somebody.

See you!